# Trying to get property of non-object (CodeIgniter)

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm trying to get data with my code below

```
public function getContentLocation(){
    $response=array();
    $result = $this->m_krb->getAllContent();
    if ($result->num_rows() > 0) {
        $response["konten"] = array();

        foreach($result->result() as $row):
            $pendaftaran = array();
            $pendaftaran["id"] = $row->id_table_petakrb;
            $pendaftaran["nama"] = $row->nama_petakrb;
            $pendaftaran["deskripsi"] = $row->deskripsi;
            $pendaftaran["foto"]='http://192.168.43.137/navigasikrb/assets/img/foto/'.$row->foto;
            $icon = $row->marker_icon;
            $marker = $this->m_krb->checkGroup($icon)->result();
            $pendaftaran["marker"] = $marker->nama_group;
            $pendaftaran["lng"] = $row->longitude;
            $pendaftaran["lat"] = $row->latitude;
            array_push($response["konten"], $pendaftaran);
        endforeach;

    // sukses
    $response["success"] = 1;

    // echo JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Tidak ada data yang ditemukan";

        echo json_encode($response);
    }
}
```

Codeigniter Model source code

```
function getAllContent(){
   $query=$this->db->query("select * from table_petakrb ");
   return $query;
}

function checkGroup($icon){
   $query=$this->db->query("select table_group.nama_group FROM table_group INNER JOIN table_petakrb ON table_petakrb.marker_icon = table_group.file_icon WHERE table_petakrb.marker_icon = '$icon' limit 1 ");
   return $query;
}
```

The problem is i'm getting "Trying to get property of non-object" error on this line

```
$pendaftaran["marker"] = $marker->nama_group;
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have show `m_krb->checkGroup($icon)` at my code above. And i have check and run the query, and it runs fine.

Comment: Well now we had better check `$this->db->query()` so we know what that returns. An object and array or false?

Comment: There's no apparent error handling of db queries in your code. Do a `var_dump($query);` in the `checkGroup` method before it returns just to see what PHP thinks the result is.

Comment: I have do a `var_dump($query);` and i get `["current_row"]=> int(0)`
What should i do?

Comment: I would guess `0 == FALSE` and therefore like I said in the beginning the query is failing

Comment: No, i have checked and run the query, and it runs fine. The error is on this line `$pendaftaran["marker"] = $marker->nama_group;`

Comment: How have you checked the query?

Comment: Yes, of course. It runs fine.

Comment: could you please look at my answer below..

Comment: Yes, i have tried your answer. But not work.

Comment: But if i change this line `$pendaftaran["marker"] = $marker->nama_group;` to `$pendaftaran["marker"] = $marker;` it works fine, and the value is `[{"nama_group":"Gedung"}]` But i want the value is just like this `"Gedung"`

What should i do? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

IN **codeigniter** The [query()](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/queries.html) function returns a database result object when "read" type queries are run, which you can use to show your results.

[result()](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html) This function returns the query result as an array of objects, or an empty array on failure. 
**row()** function returns an object.

```
 function getAllContent(){
       $query=$this->db->query("select * from table_petakrb ");
       return $query->result();
    }

    function checkGroup($icon){
       $query=$this->db->query("select table_group.nama_group FROM table_group INNER JOIN table_petakrb ON table_petakrb.marker_icon = table_group.file_icon WHERE table_petakrb.marker_icon = '$icon' limit 1 ");
       return $query->row();
    }
```

Comment: You are probably right, but who knows what is being done in the `$this->db->query()` function

Comment: result() This function returns the query result as an array of object.

Comment: Not work.
But i have put this code on controller `$marker = $this->m_krb->checkGroup($icon)->result();`

Comment: `$marker = $this->m_krb->checkGroup($icon)->row();`
this will return sinle row where result return array of objects

Comment: I have tried that too, but not work :(
Still get "Trying to get property of non-object" error

Comment: But if i change this line `$pendaftaran["marker"] = $marker->nama_group;` to `$pendaftaran["marker"] = $marker;` it works fine, and the value is `[{"nama_group":"Gedung"}]` But i want the value is just like this `"Gedung"`